# Need Assistance with stripping the microsecond from epoch time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an API to which I have to send a epoch time start and end date. The only issue is that it will not accept microseconds.

I built a time function using datatime, however it calculates the microseconds. I tried the .replace(microsecond=0), but that just leaves the .0 on the Epoch, which my API complains about. I also tried exporting to strptime, but then my .timestamp function fails to parse it as a string.

```
timestart = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 24)
timeend = datetime.now()

params = {'start_date':timestart.timestamp(), 'end_date':timeend.timestamp()}
```

i would like to basically calculate current time in Epoch and time 24 hours ago (this does not have to be super precise) that I can pass to my API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply `cast` (Type Conversion) the values of `timestart.timestamp()` and  `timeend.timestamp()`, which are `floats`, to `ints`, i.e.:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
timestart = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 24)
timeend = datetime.now()

s = int(timestart.timestamp()) 
e = int(timeend.timestamp())

params = {'start_date':s, 'end_date':e}
print(params)
```

---

Output:

```
{'start_date': 1554121647, 'end_date': 1554208047}
```

---

[Demo](https://ideone.com/bjlxAl)

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're very welcome @JessicaFerguson, thank you for being a *good citizen* and accepting the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `time.mktime()` for converting datetimes to epoch time:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

timestart = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 24)
timeend = datetime.now()

params = {
  'start_date': int(time.mktime(timestart.timetuple())),
  'end_date': int(time.mktime(timeend.timetuple()))
}

# Output
{'start_date': 1554123099, 'end_date': 1554209499}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to Pedro's one:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

timestart = (datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 24)).strftime("%s")
timeend = datetime.now().strftime("%s")

params = {'start_date':timestart,
          'end_date':timeend}
```

Output:

```
{'start_date': '1554124346', 'end_date': '1554210746'}
```